# combine two SQL queries

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Student.S_ID, COUNT(*) AS **Final_Exam_Level**
FROM Student, Exams, Exam_Allocation
WHERE (Student.S_ID)=Exam_Allocation.S_ID
  And ((Exams.Exam_ID)=Exam_Allocation.Exam_ID)
  And (Exams.Date_Taken) <= #12/31/2010#
GROUP BY Student.S_ID, Student.Course_Level
ORDER BY Student.S_ID;
```

---

```
SELECT Student.S_ID AS S_ID, Student.First_Name AS First_Name, Student.Surname AS Surname, MAX(New_Models.Date_Issued) AS Last_Course_Date, MAX(New_Models.Issue) AS Last_Issue, MAX(New_Models.Model_ID) AS Last_Model_ID, Student.Course_Level AS No_Training_Courses
FROM New_Models, New_Models_Allocation, Student
WHERE New_Models.Model_ID=New_models_Allocation.Model_ID And Student.S_ID=New_Models_Allocation.S_ID
GROUP BY Student.S_ID, Student.Course_Level, First_Name, Surname
ORDER BY MAX(New_Models.Model_ID) DESC;
```

---

**How can I add Final_Exam_Level into the second query?**

Final_Exam_Level is counting how many Exam_ID did each Student do. Exam_Allocation has two foreign keys, S_Id and Exam_ID

```
select Query_New_Models.*, Query_Exam.Final_Exam_Level
FROM (SELECT Student.S_ID AS S_ID, Student.First_Name AS First_Name, Student.Surname AS Surname, MAX(New_Models.Date_Issued) AS Last_Course_Date, MAX(New_Models.Issue) AS Last_Issue, MAX(New_Models.Model_ID) AS Last_Model_ID, Student.Course_Level AS No_Training_Courses
FROM New_Models, New_Models_Allocation, Student
WHERE New_Models.Model_ID=New_models_Allocation.Model_ID And Student.S_ID=New_Models_Allocation.S_ID
GROUP BY Student.S_ID, Student.Course_Level
ORDER BY MAX(New_Models.Model_ID) DESC)             INNER JOIN         (SELECT      Student.S_ID, COUNT(*) AS Final_Exam_Level
FROM Student, Exams, Exam_Allocation
WHERE (Student.S_ID)=Exam_Allocation.S_ID
And ((Exams.Exam_ID)=Exam_Allocation.Exam_ID)
And (Exams.Date_Taken)<=#12/31/2010#
GROUP BY Student.S_ID, Student.Course_Level
ORDER BY Student.S_ID
) ON  Query_Exam.S_ID = Query_New_Models.S_ID ;
```

Comment: Sorry, but these queries return a (very) different number of columns... so how can you merge them?

Comment: It might be easier if you state what goal you are trying to achieve, other than "combine these two queries". What should the resulting data set look like?

Comment: i want to add one column to the other. They have the same number or records though. They both show details about the technician

Comment: So what is the expected output in the end??? **HOW** do you want to combine these two queries??

Comment: How can i show u a screen shot of what I want?

Comment: Don't show a screenshot - show a set of data you have, and what output you want, as data sample (format them using the "code" button `{ ... }` in the editor

Comment: I tell you again: these two queries have a different number of columns, so the fact they return the same amount of records doesn't matter: **you can't merge them**!!!

Comment: how can i add that one more colum the first query produces to the other? Can it be done witha subquery?

Comment: Both of these queries look suspicious to me.  Using a _DISTINCT_ with _GROUP BY_ in one and the _MAX(Surname)_ in the other.  You likely should be using a subquery that performs the _GROUP BY_ before joining to get the individual details.  I don't know for sure, just something doesn't quite sit right with me.

Comment: I am not an expert, I am doing those queries by trial and eroor. But, those two queries produced the correct result in the end. I removed the MAX First_Name and the DISTINCT, it didnt affect the output. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Is Exam_Allocation facilitating a many to many between Exam and Technician?  If so is there a field on there that tells if it should be included in the Final_Exam_Level count?

Comment: @Qatrelnada, I am here to try and help. :-)  _Distinct_ is often a smell.  You really want to know why it solves your problem when you use it.

Comment: Yes. Final_Exam_Level is counting how many Exam_ID did each technician do. Exam_Allocation has two foreign keys, Technician_Id and Exam_ID

Comment: Thank you lots, I need help as this query should be done tonight. I removed the smells :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn both of them into sub-queries of a higher query

```
 select Second.*, First.Final_Exam_Level
   from (Your Second Query Here) Second
            inner join
        (Your First Query Here) First    on First.Technician_ID = Second.Technician_ID
```

Comment: I don't think they both need to be derived tables, you should be able to join the 1st query (as a derived table) directly to the 2nd

Comment: I tried to include the fields from first into the second earlier but it showed wrong results.

Comment: Can you please check the SQL i added to my post from wht I understood about what you said. Sorry, but I don't know much about SQL. I appreciate your help very much

Comment: I dont get how to do the ON command. as I dont think i can name the subqueries AS First and Second

Comment: what I wrote will work on Microsoft SQL Server, if you're using something else, you might want to tag your question mysql or postgresql or whatever the relevant technology is.  The syntax to join might be a bit different in those, but you could just look up how to subquery in your particular case.

Comment: I am using access, it did work now but the only thing am worried about is wether the teacher will accept this way of joining two queries

Comment: If it works, it's good.  That's the golden rule.  Anyway, if you're unsure, the best way to find out is to ask.